# Redirect to mobile site using ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, 51degrees

I want the user to be redirected to a mobile version of my website if they are on a mobile or tablet.

I was hoping to use 51 Degrees but they said it needs to be .net 4.0 to work and i cant upgrade from 3.5.

Does anyone know of any ways of fixing this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the engineers over at 51Degrees. Although the on-premises API does not support .NET 3.5 you can use the Cloud service available.

You will be able to make calls to our RESTful API, particularly in this case using the IsMobile property similar to:

```
string queryString = string.Format("https://cloud.51degrees.com/api/v1/*LICENCE_KEY*/match?user-agent=" + Request.UserAgent + "&values=ID+IsMobile")

string json = webClient.DownloadString(queryString);
```

This will return a JSON object that you can then format and use to re-direct.